# "Mr. Dill works ________ a big library"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, at-in

I'd appreciate a clarification on when it would be best to complete this sentence with "at" and when with "in".

Comment: Your question might be a better fit for [the English Language Learners Stack Exchange site](http://ell.stackexchange.com) than here.

Answer (score 3):

Whether you should say “Mr. Dill works at a big library” or “Mr. Dill works in a big library” depends on what the facts are and your intended emphasis.  If Mr. Dill is a librarian who works inside the library, either form can be used with little difference in meaning and no difference in grammaticality.  If Mr. Dill is a groundskeeper who works for the library but outside it, I'd say *at*, not *in*, because it is misleading to say that he works in the library.

In the example sentence, you can use any of the prepositions *at, in,* or *for*, with the same meanings for most employees.  If you want to emphasize *who*   Mr. Dill works for, use *for* or *at*, not *in*.  If you want to emphasize *where*  Mr. Dill works, use 
*in, inside,* or *outside*.

Comment: I felt as though "Mr. Dill (is a librarian that) works **in** a big library, from 8 in the morning until 4 o'clock in the afternoon." was just as good as using "at" but wasn't really sure. p.s. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score -1):

One works *at* a place, not *in* it.  That’s why we say that someone is *at* work, not that they are *in* work.  One always works *at* a business.  Oh sure, you might say that someone is “in” real estate, but that’s different.

This is true even if you name a specific building, like saying that someone works *at* the the Sears Tower or *at* the downtown library or *at* the customs house.  These are all always *at*, never *in*.

Only if you were talking about a specific physical building and specifically contrasting working outside from working inside might you ever any occasion to use *in*, and even then you would need more supporting contextual orientation.

Really, the place where you use *in* is for cities, states, or countries.  He works *in* Chicago, not *at* Chicago.  But it would then be *at* the Sears Tower, and *for* this-or-that business there.  But don’t get carried away with the *for*; people can work “at” a business, too.

Similarly, someone can work *at* CERN, but *in* Geneva.  Even if you knew the particular building, it would never be *in*, only *at*.

Comment: What about: "Mr. Dill works **in** a theater as a light-smith"? p.s. thanks for the input.

Comment: @Anon8889 'Lighting designer' or 'lighting technician' or 'electrician'. And he works in *the* theatre, which is the field (The Profession, we theatre people say), but *at* a particular theatre (probably several, since only a handful of theatres offer techs full-time year-round employment).

Comment: @Anon8889 No, that would be wrong.  It really does have to be *at* there.

Comment: It's not as clear cut as that. _Grissom works in this laboratory_ is acceptable. _Sue  works in a department store_ (_works in a department store_ scores more Google hits than _works at a department store_).  _Cheever works in the Pentagon_. And _Fred works on the market_ (for an outside market, at least) is preferable in the North of England.

Comment: @tchrist There seems little difference in preferences between US and UK usages, if one may risk a crude Google-hit comparison: _works_ **at** _a theater_ :430 // _works_ **in** _a theater_ :1610 // _works_ **at** _a theatre_ :346 // _works_ **in** _a theatre_ :2190