# I work "at" registrar's office or "in" registrar's office?

Tags: grammar, at-in

I am confused about whether I should write "I work at registrar's office" or "I work in registrar's office"

Comment: Welcome to the site. You would likely find [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) a better fit for this question.

Comment: You can say that you work *in **the** registrar's office* or *at **the** registrar's office*.

Comment: @sumelic -- The part the OP is unsure about is clear: Should they say they work *at* or *in* the registrar's office, which seems like a bad fit for this site to me.

Comment: @CarlSmith: Well, we already have several questions about this topic. Farida yasmin, see if this helps you: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40040/at-or-in-places

Comment: Also this (in fact, we even have a tag named "at-in" with 57 questions): http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105165/mr-dill-works-a-big-library

Comment: Aha! I found the answer (and the question has 16 up votes, which seems to show that some people think it is a good fit for this site): http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9749/at-or-in-the-office

Comment: `+1` I take back the bit about it being a better fit for ELL.

Comment: To be honest @sumelic, I think you were a little bit rude here today. Not in a serious way, but enough to annoy. I only suggested the other site, and you dismissed me in two words, then accused the OP of expecting a proof reading service. `+1` for the duplicate, but `-1` for manners.

Comment: 'we already have several questions about this topic' ...  So why don't we have a few close-votes here?